# Point Cloud triangulation using marching-cubes in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image, marching-cubes

I'm working on a 3D reconstruction system and want to generate a triangular mesh from the registered point cloud data using Python 3. My objects are not convex, so the marching cubes algorithm seems to be the solution.

I prefer to use an existing implementation of such method, so I tried [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_marching_cubes.html) and [Open3d](http://open3d.org/docs/tutorial/Advanced/rgbd_integration.html#extract-a-mesh) but both the APIs do not accept raw point clouds as input (note that I'm not expert of those libraries). My attempts to convert my data failed and I'm running out of ideas since the documentation does not clarify the input format of the functions.

These are my desired snippets where `pcd_to_volume` is what I need.

**scikit-image**

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import marching_cubes_lewiner

N = 10000
pcd = np.random.rand(N,3)

def pcd_to_volume(pcd, voxel_size):
    #TODO

volume = pcd_to_volume(pcd, voxel_size=0.05)

verts, faces, normals, values = marching_cubes_lewiner(volume, 0)
```

**open3d**

```py
import numpy as np
import open3d

N = 10000
pcd = np.random.rand(N,3)

def pcd_to_volume(pcd, voxel_size):
    #TODO

volume = pcd_to_volume(pcd, voxel_size=0.05)

mesh = volume.extract_triangle_mesh()
```

I'm not able to find a way to properly write the `pcd_to_volume` function. I do not prefer a library over the other, so both the solutions are fine to me.

Do you have any suggestions to properly convert my data? A point cloud is a `Nx3` matrix where `dtype=float`.

Do you know another implementation [of the marching cube algorithm] that works on raw point cloud data? I would prefer libraries like scikit and open3d, but I will also take into account github projects.

Comment: Thanks for this question. Actually I'm having the same problem now. Just curious, have you found any solutions? Thank you!

Comment: @CodingNow Not yet, unfortunately. As a workaround I've tried the [alphaShape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.html) in Matlab and it works decently. However, I haven't found any good alternative in Python.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Matlab is always the winner.

Comment: To triangulate a point cloud you can use Convex Hull.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html

Answer (score 5):

> Do you know another implementation [of the marching cube algorithm] that works on raw point cloud data?

[Hoppe](http://hhoppe.com/)'s paper [Surface reconstruction from unorganized points](http://hhoppe.com/proj/recon/) might contain the information you needed and it's [open sourced](https://rawgit.com/hhoppe/Mesh-processing-library/master/README.html).

And latest Open3D seems to be containing surface reconstruction algorithms like [alphaShape](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_alpha_shape), [ballPivoting](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_ball_pivoting) and [PoissonReconstruction](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_poisson).

---

From what I know, [marching cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) is usually used for extracting a polygonal mesh of an isosurface from a three-dimensional discrete scalar field (that's what you mean by volume). The algorithm does not work on raw point cloud data.

Hoppe's algorithm works by first generating a signed distance function field (a SDF volume), and then passing it to marching cubes. This can be seen as an implementation to you `pcd_to_volume` and it's not the only way!

If the raw point cloud is all you have, then the situation is a little bit constrained. As you might see, the [Poisson reconstruction](http://hhoppe.com/proj/poissonrecon/) and [Screened Poisson reconstruction](http://hhoppe.com/proj/screenedpoisson/) algorithm both implement `pcd_to_volume` in their own way (they are highly related). However, they needs additional point normal information, and the normals have to be consistently oriented. (For consistent orientation you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60346126/7413964)).

While some [Delaunay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) based algorithm (*they do not use marching cubes*) like alphaShape and [this](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/index.html) may not need point normals as input, for surfaces with complex topology, it's hard to get a satisfactory result due to orientation problem. And the [graph cuts method](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4408892/) can use visibility information to solve that.

---

Having said that, if your data comes from depth images, you will usually have visibility information. And you can use [TSDF](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/237170.237269) to build a good surface mesh. Open3D have [already implemented that](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/reconstruction_system/integrate_scene.html).

Comment: I will definitely look at those papers. Thank you! I'm not expert of 3D reconstruction and your answer is very instructive. Concerning my data, I generate the point clouds from depth images so the visibility information is available: I will check also TSDF.

Comment: FYI if the depth data comes from a continuously scanning equipment, tsdf is used the most (my personal experience). And if that is the case, you may want to look at [KinectFusion](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ismar2011.pdf) and a series of following work.

Comment: And if you depth pictures are just taken at separate spots at discrete time, then after normal estimation for your point cloud, screened Poisson might just be good enough for you.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else coming across this post, if you can't construct a numpy array from your points that could be used with [marching_cubes](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes) in scikit-image, Open3D has some options for [surface reconstruction](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/Advanced/surface_reconstruction.html) that may not have been available previously.