# Is it possible to reconstruct(interpolate) a 3D surface using skimage marching cube from 3D point cloud?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image, point-clouds, marching-cubes

I have a 3D point cloud:

```
    import numpy as np
    x = np.array([...])
    y = np.array([...])
    z = np.array([...])
```

Is it possible to "reconstruct" a 3D surface using `skiamge`'s `marching_cubes` from this 3D point cloud?
I checked skimage's documentation but didn't have a clue. Any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to "reconstruct" a 3D surface using skiamge's marching_cubes from this 3D point cloud?

From what I know, you can not use marching cubes directly on unorganized point cloud. You have to pass a volumetric field to it.

---

To generate 3D surface from raw point cloud, you can use the algorithm detailed in 
 [Surface reconstruction from unorganized points](http://hhoppe.com/proj/recon/) and it's [open sourced](https://rawgit.com/hhoppe/Mesh-processing-library/master/README.html).

Or you can use a Delaunay based method like [this](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/index.html). [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/index.html) have provided a [Delaunay implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html), but you still have to extract surface from it.

For more information, see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60690334/7413964).