# Consistent normal calculation of a point cloud

Tags: graphics, 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, open3d

Is there a library in python or c++ that is capable of estimating normals of point clouds in a consistent way?
In a consistent way I mean that the orientation of the normals is globally preserved over the surface.

For example, when I use python open3d package:

> ```
> downpcd.estimate_normals(search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(
>     radius=4, max_nn=300))
> ```

I get an inconsistent results, where some of the normals point inside while the rest point outside.

many thanks[image: estimated normals (black lines indicate outside directed normals)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the viewpoint from where each point was captured, it can be used to orient the normals.
I assume that this not the case - so given your situation, which seems rather watertight and uniformly sampled, **mesh reconstruction** is promising.

PCL library offers many alternatives in the [surface module](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/group__surface.html). For the sake of normal estimation, I would start with either:

- [ConcaveHull](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/classpcl_1_1_concave_hull.html)
- [Greedy projection triangulation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/classpcl_1_1_greedy_projection_triangulation.html)

Although simple, they should be enough to produce a single coherent mesh.

Once you have a mesh, each triangle defines a normal (the cross product). It is important to note that a mesh isn't just a collection of independent faces. The faces are connected and this connectivity enforces a coherent orientation across the mesh.

`pcl::PolygonMesh` is an "[half edge data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list)". This means that every triangle face is defined by an ordered set of vertices, which defines the orientation:
*order of vertices => order of cross product => well defined unambiguous normals*

You can either use the normals from the mesh (nearest neighbor), or calculate a low resolution mesh and just use it to orient the cloud.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE**: ***GOOD NEWS!***

The *tangent plane* algorithm is now implemented in Open3D!
The [source code](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/blob/v0.11.2/cpp/open3d/geometry/PointCloud.h#L228) and the [documentation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html#open3d.geometry.PointCloud.orient_normals_consistent_tangent_plane).

You can just call `pcd.orient_normals_consistent_tangent_plane(k=15)`.
And `k` is the knn graph parameter.

---

***Original answer:***

Like Mark said, if your point cloud comes from multiple depth images, then you can call `open3d.geometry.orient_normals_towards_camera_location(pcd, camera_loc)` before concatenating them together (assuming you're using python version of [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/)).

---

However, if you don't have that information, you can use the ***tangent plane*** algorithm:

1. **Build knn-graph for your point cloud.**
   The graph nodes are the points. Two points are connected if one is the other's k-nearest-neighbor.
2. **Assign weights to the edges in the graph.**
   The weight associated with edge *(i, j)* is computed as *1 - |**n**<sub>i</sub> ⋅ **n**<sub>j</sub>|*
3. **Generate the *minimal spanning tree* of the resulting graph.**
4. **Rooting the tree at an initial node,
   traverse the tree in depth-first order, assigning each node an
   orientation that is consistent with that of its parent.**

Actually the above algorithm comes from Section 3.3 of [Hoppe](http://hhoppe.com/)'s 1992
SIGGRAPH paper [Surface Reconstruction from Unorganized Points](http://hhoppe.com/proj/recon/). The algorithm is also [open sourced](https://github.com/hhoppe/Mesh-processing-library).

AFAIK the algorithm does not guarantee a perfect orientation, but it should be good enough.